# how to remove dummy permission in Files and Folders on Security and Privacy?

Tags: macos, permissions, macos-catalina, system-preferences

I've installed Adobe Creative Cloud and removed few days ago,

but it still remains 'com.adobe.acc.installer.v2' on Files and Folders permission.

How can I remove this?

I even cannot find this file on my mac.

Waiting for your intelligence.

Thank you.

Comment: Unless it's absolutely vital that you get rid of it, you can leave it as is. It's a precaution all application vendors take, in case you want to reinstall their product after uninstalling them. It speeds things up on reinstall, but is of no consequence, security-wise.

Comment: @Didier Thanks for reply. it seems not disturb my mac, but pretty sure it's quite annoying because it is dummy. is there nothing to solve with terminal?

Comment: Yes, it's annoying, because it keeps reappearing every time you close it, but it's just a warning that the 32-bit version of Adobe CC you had installed is not compatible with macOS Catalina, which only runs 64-bit applications now. You can try this: open System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Check Allow apps downloaded from App Store and identified developers > Click Open Anyway. Restart your Mac and check if the message still pops up. You can also delete the com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist file in ~/Library/Preferences/Adobe or /LIbrary/Preferences/Adobe and Startup Items.

Comment: Thanks a lot. HND !

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

**1. Delete the following files :**

- /Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.acc.installer.v2
- /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist

or

- /System/Volumes/Data/Library/PrivilegedHelperTools/com.adobe.acc.installer.v2
- /System/Volumes/Data/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.adobe.acc.installer.v2.plist

**2. Open Terminal and execute the bellow command :**

```
sudo tccutil reset SystemPolicyDesktopFolder
```

**3. Reboot**

**P.S.** If com.adobe.acc.installer.v2 has access to other locations, the guide for using **tccutil** bellow :

```
sudo tccutil reset CATEGORY
```

CATEGORIES :

- Accessibility
- AddressBook
- AppleEvents
- Calendar
- Camera
- Microphone
- Photos
- Reminders
- ScreenCapture
- SystemPolicyAllFiles
- SystemPolicyDesktopFolder
- SystemPolicyDeveloperFiles
- SystemPolicyDocumentsFolder
- SystemPolicyDownloadsFolder
- SystemPolicyNetworkVolumes
- SystemPolicyRemovableVolumes
- SystemPolicySysAdminFiles

Best,
Elie